# Future Diary plot explanation, in regards to the winning condition

Tags: plot-explanation, the-future-diary

I am confused about *[The Future Diary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Diary)*'s winning condition.

[image: posture of the movie The future diary]

The way I understand it is that when Yuno killed Eighth, at that point Yukiteru was supposed to become god. My reasoning is that in the first universe, Yuno won the game and became God when Yukiteru committed suicide. Then she moved to the second universe and killed her second-universe self.

So when Yuno kills Eighth, that should make Yukkii the winner of the game and the universe's new god, as he's the only survivor left from that universe. He does not become god at that point, however, so I must be missing something here.

Also, what happens to the first universe? It does not have a god after Yuno kills herself in the third universe, so does that mean the first universe is destroyed?

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I edit some spoiler tags into this, because as someone who's seen *Future Diary*, you're dropping some massive, ***massive*** spoilers here.

Comment: @F1Krazy Hi, not at all, I had hidden everything at first anyway. Thanks

Comment: @F1Krazy It does make it a little hard to read mess, though. Frankly, anyone who's clicking a plot explanation question about *Future Diary* knows what he's getting himself into anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game rules don't take into account the fact that Yuno is actually from another universe.

All that matters is that she's a Diary holder, just the same as the other eleven. So when Eighth dies, there are still *two* participants left: Yukkii and Yuno. (In fact, I believe Ninth was still alive at that point as well, so Yukkii wouldn't have won the game anyway. It's been a while since I watched the show, though, so I don't quite remember.)

As for your other question, I'm afraid I don't quite remember the answer to that either, but it's most likely that Universe 1 was indeed destroyed, either when Yuno jumped across to Universe 2, or when she killed herself in Universe 3.